# What is the proper way to look for undefined value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code:

```
if (array.indexOf("undefined")===-1){
    do something...
  }
```

My initial arrays is this:

> array=[,,,,,,];

It gets filled with values as the program goes on but i want the function to stop when there are no undefined spaces. The above syntax though is not correct. Anybody can tell me why.

Comment: Need more info. Do you know the final number of spaces to be filled? Are they filled out of sequence? Are the spaces defined by the member having the actual value of `undefined`, or is it simply a hole in the array?

Comment: That test looks for the **string** `"undefined"`.

Comment: `array.findIndex(function(x) { return x === undefined })` seems to work

Comment: What do you do with your array when you check your condition?

Comment: this is the initial array var spacesArray = [, , , , , , , ,];. They are being filled randomly with two different values. When it is filled the array is assigning a value of win and resets the array to its initial state

Comment: You want not to do anything if array contains non empty value? Or you do something when iterate on array? Or you want to know index of non `undefined` value?

Comment: So you have a fixed array length? Why don´t you initialize an empty array `yourArray=[]` and `push` your random numbers into it? Then you can check for `myArray.Length == x`.

Comment: When array contains at least 1 undefined value, not to do anything. When every index in the array is been filled to mark 'a win' and reset the array.

Comment: Martin E, because i need to have predefined allocated spaces in the array and check if they have a value or not

Comment: @Kostis: So if you know the `.length` up front, why not maintain a counter that gets incremented when a new value is added, and runs your code when the counter matches the `.length`?

Comment: Yes that could be a very neat solution. I think there are various ways to solve this but i was really curious why indexOf - undefined was not working.

Comment: Another way to check for undefined values could be the `array.some()` function. It returns a boolen and allows a function to be defined. `if(!array.some(function(val) {
             return val === undefined;
        }))
        {
            // doSomething();
        }` But as you want to be with the `indexOf`, its just another way to achieve what you want :)

Comment: @Kostis: `.indexOf()` doesn't work because it explicitly ignores holes in the array. There are several array methods that do this. I added a solution like the one I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks for the string "undefined". You want to look for the first index containing an `undefined` value. The best way is to use `findIndex`:

```
if(array.findIndex(x=>x===undefined) !== -1) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem altough I am still not very familiar with arrow functions. So basically there is no way to look for an undefined value with indexOf? (and actually i look for == - 1)

Comment: You can replace the arrow function with `function(x) {return x === undefined;}`. No way to search for `undefined` with `indexOf`.

Comment: You can certainly search for `undefined` with `.indexOf`. You just can't find holes in a sparse array, because `.indexOf` ignores them.

Comment: @Kostis: Using `.findIndex()` or looking for the *value* `undefined` will give you false positives if the `undefined` value is actually included in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var ind in array) {
 if(array[ind] === undefined) {
   doSomething();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check didn't work because you passed the string `"undefined"` instead the the value itself. Also, `.indexOf()` is designed to explicitly ignore holes in the array.

It seems wasteful to use iteration to detect holes in the array. Instead you could just track how many holes have been filled by using a counter, and execute your code when the counter matches the length.

Either way, the proper way to detect a hole at a particular index is to use the `in` operator.

Here's a class-based solution for reuse:

```js
class SpacesArray extends Array {
  constructor(n, callback) {
    super(n);
    this.callback = callback;
    this.counter = 0;
  }
  
  fillHole(n, val) {
    if (!(n in this)) {
      this.counter++;
      console.log("filling hole", n);
    }
    this[n] = val;
    
    if (this.counter === this.length) {
      this.callback();
    }
  }
}

// Usage
var sa = new SpacesArray(10, function() {
  console.log("DONE! " + this);
});

// Emulate delayed, random filling of each hole.
for (let i = 0; i < sa.length; i++) {
  const ms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
  setTimeout(() => sa.fillHole(i, i), ms);
}
```